# Every associated prime of a divisorial ideal has height one

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian

Let $R$ be a Noetherian normal domain and $I$ a nonzero $R$-ideal. Show that if $I$ is divisorial, then every associated prime of $I$ has height one. ($I$ is said to be *divisorial* if $(R:(R:I))=I$, where $(R:I)=\{k\in K\mid kI\subset R, K$ is the field of fractions of $R\}$.)

It seems like I have to prove that by localizing $R$ at every associated prime $P$ of $I$, $P_P$ is invertible.

Comment: Can you give some context into what you know and from what angle you're approaching this? Are you familiar with Krull domains and/or $*$-operations? There are a lot of approaches to this...  in any case, a good start would be to try to prove that $P$ is divisorial.

Comment: We can find the answer on page 486, Commutative Algebra by N.BOURBAKI.